# what is use of (..) double dot in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have got a script of stored procedure from my senior, like :

```
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'create procedure [dbo].[up_transfer_data_from_isfoc_to_unicode_sp]
as
begin
declare @errx as int
begin try   

truncate table u_lrc..dir 
truncate table u_lrc..k_2 
truncate table u_lrc..k_name 
truncate table u_lrc..k_gata 
truncate table u_lrc..order1 
truncate table u_lrc..remark 

  insert into u_lrc..dir 
 select code,[lrc].name 
 from lrc..dir
```

Where dir, K_2, k_name and others are Table names whereas lrc and u_lrc are databases. u_lrc is a copy of lrc database.

What is (..) is doing here and examples of its usage ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exec with .. (Double dot)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275740/exec-with-double-dot)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server uses three (really four) part naming for objects stored in the database -- tables, functions, stored procedures, and so on.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187879(v=sql.105).aspx).

The three part names are ...

Typing the schema name gets cumbersome and many people just use the default schema of `dbo`.

So, the `..` is a reference to the table in the `u_lrc` database using the default schema.

I should point out that the fourth part is optional (as are the second and third parts).  It is for the server name.